# Can somebody explain me why is this C code not compiling my else if statement?

Tags: c, if-statement

So I wrote this C code but cant find the bug of why is the compiler not getting the else if statement.

```
    #include<stdio.h>

#define IN 1
#define OUT 0;

main() {
    int c, nl, nw, nc, state;
    c = nl = nw = nc = 0;

    state = OUT;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        ++nc;

        if(c == '\n')
            ++nl;

        if(c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == ' ') 
            state = OUT;
        else if(state == OUT) {
            state = IN;
            ++nw;
        }
    }

    printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc);

    getchar();
}
```

I got an error saying  "'else' without a previous 'if'"

Comment: your `OUT` macro shouldn't end by `;`. no macro should end by `;` BTW.

Comment: Why not use more braces

Comment: A good reason to always use curly braces

Comment: in that case, braces won't help. A `switch/case` would, on the other hand.

Comment: Misplaced `;` in macro

Comment: if tried to use curly braces but I get another error that says that after the OUT in the else if statement the compiler was expecting a ')' @Ed_Heal

Comment: @Peter `#define OUT 0;` is wrong.

Comment: I have copied this from The C programming language book and it uses ; after the OUT @jean-françois-fabre

Comment: Check my first comment. the colon at the end of the macro is the sole reason it doesn't compile. Well, maybe it's not explicit enough: `hello.c:4:14: error: expected ')' before ';' token
 #define OUT 0;
              ^
hello.c:20:26: note: in expansion of macro 'OUT'
         else if(state == OUT) {
                          ^`

Comment: @ravelinx someone should tell them that they're wrong. Or all of us & the compiler is wrong.

Comment: @MDXF: please do not *fix* the questions! it makes the comments and answers inconsistent with the *improved* question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6451573/jean-fran%c3%a7ois-fabre) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40031231/can-somebody-explain-me-why-is-this-c-code-not-compiling-my-else-if-statement/40031305?noredirect=1#comment67339757_40031231) in the comments, your problem is the trailing semicolon in this `#define`:

```
#define OUT 0;
```

That causes your code to effectively look like this:

```
    if(c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == ' ') 
        state = OUT;
    ;  // The "else" would go here, but you've already completed the "if"

    else if(state == OUT) {   // Now there is no "if" to associate with
        state = IN;
        ++nw;
    }
```

The preprocessor has the ability to cause all kinds of problems like this, which is a good reason to avoid it when possible. (This coming from a guy who has used cpp to do dirty, disgusting things).

In this case, an anonymous `enum` is the way to go:

```
enum {
    OUT = 0,
    IN = 1,
};
```

Also, this is a matter of style, but I always include curly braces, except for simple conditionals with no `else`:

```
// OK
if (ok)
    foo();

// Not OK
if (ok)
    foo();
else if (x == 3) {
    lots();
    of();
    stuff();
}
else
    bad();
```

Comment: you showed us how to turn a typo on a book into a good answer. C works in mysterious ways :)

Answer (score 2):

The macro `OUT` is defined as `0;`.

In your second if statement, this becomes

```
if(c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == ' ') 
    state = 0;;
else
```

or written more clearly

```
if(c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == ' ') 
    state = 0;
;
else
```

Because of this second semicolon, there is no previous if, where the else could belong to.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this if.
The macro OUT here:

```
else if(state == OUT) {
            state = IN;
            ++nw;
}
```

turns into

```
else if(state == 0;) {
            state = IN;
            ++nw;
}
```

After the preprocessing stage. Change the macro so it won't have a ;, and it'll work. Usually, macros don't ever hold ; (Unless they have multiple lines)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Yes, yours is accurate. I wonder why not use curly braces? Haha

Comment: Always use curly braces!